# Proving that isomorphism of field extension is an equivalence relation

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I'm reading Stewart's Galois Theory Third Edition. In Chapter 4 he gives the definition of the isomorphism of field extension as follows:

> An isomorphism between two field extension $l : K \rightarrow \hat{K}$, $j: L \rightarrow \hat{L}$ is a pair $(\lambda, \mu)$ of field isomorphisms $\lambda: K \rightarrow L, \mu : \hat{K} \rightarrow \hat{L}$ such that $j(\lambda(k)) = \mu(l(k))$ for all $k \in K$.

Then in the exercise he asks to prove that this isomorphism of field extensions is an equivalence relation. The reflectivity and transitivity are easy to see for me but I'm not sure if I'm dealing with symmetry correctly.

I say (keep the notations as in the definition):

> If $\lambda \sim \mu$ then we have $j(\lambda(K)) = \mu(l(K))$, then there exists $j^{-1}$, $l^{-1}$ such that $j^{-1}(\mu(\hat{K})) = \lambda(l^{-1}(\hat{K}))$ which gives $\mu \sim \lambda$.

However, the inverse of a field extension hasn't defined yet so I'm not sure if this is legit. Or maybe I'm just going the wrong track? I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't understand the notation. Which are the base fields? Which are the extension? What are $l,j$?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion -- $K$ and $L$ are the base fields. $\hat{K}$ and $\hat{L}$ are the field extension.

Comment: I suppose $l,j$ are the inclusions of $K$ and $L$ in their extensions right? $(\lambda, \mu)$ is a pair of maps from where to where?

Comment: @Maffred Ah I just edited it -- $\lambda$ is from $K$ to $L$ and $\mu$ is from $\hat{K}$ to $\hat{L}$. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You can draw a rectangular maps diagram. The definition is saying it commutes. Now if you add a new line to the diagram with a third line for a new filed extension which commutes with the second line, of course the whole diagram commutes. You got transitivity. You can do the same for the other requirements for equivalence.

Comment: @Maffred Yes I got the reflectivity and transitivity but not quite sure how the symmetry comes from. Seems like the symmetry has to involve some of the map in the diagram being inverted(?) In my description above, I inverted $l$ and $j$...

Comment: I suppose $(\lambda,\mu)$ are isomorphisms of fields, or this definition is useless! Check the definitions of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field extension is a triple $(K,l,K_1)$. We say that this is isomorphic to $(L,j,L_1)$ if we have an isomorphism $(\lambda,\mu)$ which is composed by two maps since we need the map between the base fields, and the map between the extended fields, and we want that the diagram commutes. We want to show that the field extensions are divided into equivalent classes (not the isomorphisms). Of course a field extension is isomorphic to itself since you can chose $(\lambda,\mu) = (Id_K,Id_{K_1})$ to get riflessivity. If you have $(K,l,K_1) \simeq (L,j,L_1)$ with isomorphism $(\lambda_1,\mu_1)$ and $(L,j,L_1) \simeq (H,t,H_1)$ with isomorphism $(\lambda_2,\mu_2)$ you can take $(\lambda,\mu) = (\lambda_2\lambda_1,\mu_2\mu_1)$ to get transitivity. If you want simmetry just take $(\lambda^{-1},\mu^{-1})$.

Comment: Ah! I see. So similar to what I commended under A.P.'s answer, we could have $\mu^{-1}(j(L)) = l(\lambda^{-1}(L))$ which gives $\mu^{-1} \sim \lambda^{-1}$ but how should we know $\mu \sim \lambda$ from here?

Comment: NONONO! You are not looking for $\mu \simeq \lambda$! I write a new ansewr more clear!

Comment: Edited!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks! I get this from drawing the diagram also. I guess I don't understand why the symmetry is to prove "if $\lambda \sim \mu$, then $\lambda^{-1} \sim \mu^{-1}$" instead of "if $\lambda \sim \mu$, then $\mu \sim \lambda$"? Or maybe these two statements are essentially equivalent but why?

Comment: NO! you are not comparing them, you are comparing filed extensions. Reread my answer, I changed it completely! You are comparing field extensions, not maps!!!!

Comment: I now understand!!! Indeed I had a misconception before! Thank you this gets really clear now!

Answer (score 0):

You want to invert $\lambda$ and $\mu$, not the extensions (these generally aren't invertible...). In more detail:

You want to show that $l \sim j$ implies $j \sim l$, that is, you wand to find a pair that gives you an isomorphism between the extensions $j$ and $l$ given that you already have such a pair $(\lambda,\mu)$ between $l$ and $j$. I claim that $(\lambda^{-1},\mu^{-1})$ is a pair that yields an isomorphism between $j$ and $l$. We have to show that $$l(\lambda^{-1}(l)) = \mu^{-1}(j(l)) \, \text{ for all } l \in L.$$ This is equivalent to $$\mu(l(\lambda^{-1}(l)) = j(l),$$
and since $(\lambda,\mu)$ is an isomorphism of field extensions between $l$ and $j$ (i.e., we are assuming from that start that $l \sim j$), this is equivalent to $$ j(\lambda(\lambda^{-1}(l)) = j(l),$$ which is obviously true for all $l \in L$.

Comment: So if we can invert $\mu$ and $\lambda$, we have $\mu^{-1}(j(L)) = l(\lambda^{-1}(L))$ which gives $\mu^{-1} \sim \lambda^{-1}$? Then what should we do next?

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed version. I think I'm baffled by the idea that $\lambda^{-1} \sim \mu{-1}$ is equivalent to $\mu \sim \lambda$. Why is this true?

Comment: @Shiyue I'm not sure what you mean. The equivalence relation is defined on the set of field extensions. So what we're really showing here is that $l \sim j$ implies that $j \sim l$.

Comment: I see! I had a misconception before..Thanks for your answer! I now understand!